# Separate bank account for security deposit from tenant

Tags: bank-account, landlord

My state (Maryland) requires me to have a separate bank account (escrow) for the security deposit collected from the Tenants.

My questions:

1) Do banks have separate bank account for such a purpose or just a normal checking/saving account will suffice?

2) Can this account be re-used for other tenants once the first tenant moves out?

3) Are there any fees associated with such bank account?

Answer (score 3):

Per [Md. REAL PROPERTY Code Ann. § 8-203](http://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2005/grp/8-203.html):

> (d)      (1)      (i)      The landlord shall maintain all security
>   deposits in federally insured financial institutions, as defined in §
>   1-101 of the Financial Institutions Article, which do business in the
>   State.
>
> (ii)      Security deposit accounts shall be maintained in branches of the financial institutions which are located
>   within the State and the accounts shall be devoted exclusively to
>   security deposits and bear interest.
>
> (iii)      A security deposit shall be deposited in an account within 30 days after the landlord receives it.
>
> (iv)      The aggregate amount of the accounts shall be sufficient in amount to equal all security deposits for which the
>   landlord is liable.
>
> (2)      (i)      In lieu of the accounts described in paragraph (1) of this subsection, the landlord may hold the security
>   deposits in insured certificates of deposit at branches of federally
>   insured financial institutions, as defined in § 1-101 of the Financial
>   Institutions Article, located in the State or in securities issued by
>   the federal government or the State of Maryland.
>
> (ii)      In the aggregate certificates of deposit or securities shall be sufficient in amount to equal all security
>   deposits for which the landlord is liable.

As such, one or more accounts at your preference; it's up to the bank how to treat the account, so it may be a personal account or it may be a 'commercial' account depending on how they treat it (but it must be separate from your personal funds).  A CD is perhaps the easiest way to go, as it's not a separate account exactly but it's easily separable from your own funds (and has better interest).

You should also note (further down on that page) that you must pay 3% interest, once per six months; so try to get an account that pays as close as possible to that.  You likely won't get 3% right now even in a CD, so consider this as an expense (and you'll probably find many people won't take security deposits in many situations as a result).

Comment: It has to be a bank account so CD option does not work. May be CD is a type of bank account but its also considered an Investment.

Comment: @Asdfg: Bullet point number 2 specifically mentions both CDs and some investments (securities issued by the state or federal government) as acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In Massachusetts, we have a similar law. Each tenant fills out a W9 and the account is in their name. You need to find a bank willing to do this at  no cost, else fees can be problematic. With today's rates, any fee at all will exceed interest earned.

Comment: In Maryland, Account does not need to be in the Tenant's name.